# Can I suppress the message from jquery validation, but still have it apply a new background colour?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-mobile

Now that we have the placeholder attribute to give a good example of what should be entered into an input field, and given that on a mobile phone space is at a premium, I would like to know if there is a way to get JQuery Validate to simply set the background colour of input fields to indicate whether they are valid or not. As I'm using jQuery mobile most of my inputs including radio button groups are in containers, so I guess setting a "ui-field-contain error" class background to a color (that I define in css) without issuing the error message is what I'd like to do. Is it possible?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with in the end. Overriding the highlight and unhighlight methods allowed me to add an appropriate class to the containers of the inputs and highlight them as I liked - in the end I decided upon red or green borders. Finally, I chose to keep the error text and display it in the manner of a tooltip.

```
$(".product_type_form").validate({
    validClass: "data-valid", 
    errorClass: "data_invalid",
    errorElement: "span",                     
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if ($(element).is("input[type='radio']")) {
            container = $(element).parents('div.ui-controlgroup-controls');
        } else {
            container = $(element).parents('div.ui-input-text');
        }             
        error.insertBefore(container);
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if ($(element).is("input[type='radio']")) {
            container = $(element).parents('div.ui-controlgroup-controls');    
        } else {
            container = $(element).parents('div.ui-input-text');
        }
        container.addClass(errorClass);
        container.removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if ($(element).is("input[type='radio']")) {
            container = $(element).parents('div.ui-controlgroup-controls');    
        } else {
            container = $(element).parents('div.ui-input-text');
        }            
        container.addClass(validClass);
        container.removeClass(errorClass);            
    }
});
```